# Ionic 2: Use cordova plugin with Typescript that has its own namespace

Tags: typescript, ionic2, undefined, cordova-plugins, typescript-typings

I want to use the  [`LibraryHelper` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-library-helper) in my Ionic 2 app, but the docs for it defines its usage statically, e.g.:

`LibraryHelper.saveVideoToLibrary(....)`

NOT through:

`window.plugins.LibraryHelper.saveVideoToLibrary(....`

When I write the first line in my Typescript .ts file, I get the error:

`Cannot find name 'LibraryHelper'`

**Q) How do I import the LibraryHelper plugin into my Ionic 2 app and be able to reference it without it - being undefined as above?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to install the plugin with the `--save` option

```
ionic plugin add cordova-library-helper --save
```

You need to declare the global object `LibraryHelper` in your class after your imports.

```
//imports
declare var LibraryHelper:any;
@Component({..})
//..
```

When you are using in your component, just make sure to wrap within

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
  LibraryHelper.saveVideoToLibrary(....)
})
```

Comment: I've done exactly that and the LibraryHelper object is just empty when I try to use it: {}

Comment: you are testing on a device?

Comment: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-how-to-use-cordova-plugins/ I listed the steps you do for any general cordova plugin..Maybe it has to do with the plugin itself

Comment: Ok, well you fixed the typescript error, so you win! Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok..if it helps you can check out https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ and see if any of it fits your use case its easier to integrate